# Wrong architecture error when loading lgi

Tags: lua, architecture, require, luarocks, zerobrane

I have Lua 5.3 installed on my Mac Sierra OS with Luarocks and it seems to be working fine. In fact, I have `lgi` installed and this file works without error from the terminal when I run it:

```
local lgi = require'lgi'
```

However, in ZeroBrane with the 5.3 interpreter selected, the same file produces the following error:

```
/ZeroBraneStudio/bin/lua.app/Contents/MacOS/lua53: error loading module 'lgi.corelgilua51' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.so':
dlopen(/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
stack traceback:
    [C]: in ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.3/lgi/core.lua:14: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.3/lgi/init.lua:19: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.3/lgi.lua:19: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /Users/andrew/src/gstreamer/fun.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I also tried using the installed interpreter:

```
path.lua = "/usr/local/bin/lua"
```

but this had no effect.

SO... does anyone have any pointers? Why does the terminal work but ZeroBrane complain about the wrong architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lua53 binary that comes with ZeroBrane Studio is i386 executable (32bit), but the library you are using is probably 64bit, hence the message about the wrong architecture.

```
path.lua = "/usr/local/bin/lua"
```

> but this had no effect.

If you are using it with Lua 5.3 interpreter, you'll need to set `path.lua53` instead; try `path.lua53 = "/usr/local/bin/lua"` (assuming `/usr/local/bin/lua` is Lua 5.3 interpreter). See [Interpreter Path](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#interpreter-path) section in the documentation for details/examples.

Also, this filename (`/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.so`) looks suspicious, as it mixes 5.3 and 51, but if it works from the command line, it should work from the IDE as well when you set `path.lua53`.

Comment: Great product and great support. Thank you Paul! One quick note: High Sierra is the last OS where Apple will support 32bit "without compromises". When compiling Lua, I don't *think* that I explicitly flagged it to compile in 64bit, but I could be wrong. If I am correct, it might be reasonable to make the Mac versions of Lua 64bit, if only to avoid these sorts of edge cases. FWIW.

Comment: Good point. I'll definitely look into that as part of the next component upgrade as the binaries will need to be recompiled anyway.